# Removing access from an issuer account

Tags: accounts, security, multi-sig, issuing

I was helped by a developer to originally create my token. Because they have dissapeared I am trying to figure out how to remove access to the token by the Issuer account and give that authorization to a new account so that the token can't be compromised.

What is the best practice - I am fine with not being able to issue more tokens in the future but I'd like to keep the ability to set an anchor as my business grows.

What would you suggest?
I've looked all through documentation for what to do if issuer account is compromised.